# The dotnet cli shows 1.0 even though I have installed .Net Core 1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have downloaded and installed the latest .Net Core from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core, but after the installation I opened up a cmd prompt and `> dotnet --version` still shows 1.0.0-preview2-003131

Could someone explain what I'm missing here please?

Comment: have you checked the x64 vs. x86 program file folders (on windows). I remember there was a bug in the installer mentioned in a community standup a while ago.

Comment: I only found dotnet.exe in C:\Program Files\dotnet and no where else, it's 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update for new comers - 2018-08-01

The original answer was highly targeted at the understanding that the OP had with context at the time (2016). Core has come a long way in the last few years so if you are coming at this now, you might not even know what a global.json and SDK pinning is because it is no longer part of the default template when creating a new project.

Essentially, the CLI will use the highest installed version of .Net Core by default. However, should you choose to, you can dictate a specific version of .Net Core to be used by all apps in nested folders by creating a global.json and setting a specific SDK version. If you do this, you'll get errors when the incorrect version is installed.

The Core team is pretty good about not causing any breaking changes and as described above have opted to remove pinning by default. This actually recently caused some [issues for some people](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/1086) because they had not pinned to the version they had built their app against. I personally prefer to pin to the version I'm building against and update it explicitly.

To add extra confusion, the SDK versions don't line up with the version numbers of the .Net Core releases so you really have to "just know" which version to use for what.

**For anyone coming to this answer now, the problem that the OP had here was that he didn't realize the global.json was pinning his version nor why the version was so different than the .Net Core version.**

---

#### Original answer:

The command line is context specific.  My guess is you are running from a project that has a global.json in a parent folder that references an older version.

Old Global.json

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}
```

Change your global.json to:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"
  }
}
```

This change will make the dotnet cli respect the new version in your projects so you can choose when to upgrade your projects. This is how you can have multiple versions of dotnet on your machine and not have to update every one of your projects at once.

[Edit - SDK version confusion]

Just to note, the SDK version you have installed is indeed the 1.1 version of the SDK.  The installer indicates the new version of the SDK for 1.1.  I've captured a screenshot below.

[image: Core 1.1 Installer banner]

Comment: I updated my global.json to   "sdk": {   "version": "1.1.0-*"  } but still got the following error when building my project.
Error  The project is configured to use .NET Core SDK version 1.1.0-* which is not installed or cannot be found under the path C:\Program Files\dotnet.

Comment: @fanray Just comment it out and run "dotnet --version".  That'll tell you what to replace it with.  It's probably something like "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177".  dotnet core is on 1.1, but I find the tooling doesn't represent the same versions even though it is the right version for 1.1

Comment: @fanray I've updated my answer to be more specific to your situation and a screenshot to show that the SDK version provided is the 1.1 version.

Comment: Thank you @Runesun I updated global.json to "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177" and it worked, though it's confusing me that if I installed 1.1 why dotnet cli says it's 1.0 and why global.json has 1.0 and everything in my project.json uses 1.1 and then everything works all of sudden.

Comment: This is so confusing. I came across the same issue. I just installed it and I get the same image as above. Clearly the image above says Core 1.1.0. Yet "dotnet --version" says "1.0.0-preview4-004233". It's not really displaying the version of Core. It's displaying the version of the SDK. Why aren't they both the same?

Comment: Different versions because they are different things. One version for the dotnet core framework. The other is for the dotnet cli and tooling.  Being core 1.1 doesn't tell me if you are using project.json or csproj. Your sdk version does and is how the cli knows the right way to handle your project.  Also, framework updates won't have to wait for tooling updates because of the separation.  Think of it like those cross functional tools you've probably built to support your projects. They aren't tied to your products version. Just need to know which version of the tool to use.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @helrich  See update. It was answered based on how projects were built at the time (2016) and the context a developer would have. Admittedly not very future proof. I've added a section about the global.json and SDK pinning being removed by default because most people don't know that it is even a thing thus would never look for the file.